# Remove duplicate sequences using FoldLeft/Right

Tags: scala

Hi i wonder how could i remove duplicate sequences using FoldLeft. I implemented a code for lists with small changes but it returns List(3, 1, 4, 2, 1), but for seq = Seq(1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3) it should return  Seq(1, 2, 4, 1, 3)

```
def deStutter[A](seq: Seq[A]): Seq[A] = {
seq.foldLeft(Seq[A]()) {
  case (Seq(), item) => Seq(item)
  case (ls, item) if (ls.head == item)  => ls
  case (ls, item) => (item +: ls)
}
println(deStutter(Seq(1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3)))
```

Comment: Have you attempted to code it yourself? Show your code; explain where you got stuck; and ask a question that will help you get unstuck

Comment: Also, note that `contains` on a **List** is very slow, it is usually better to keep a **Set** alongside the traversal.

Comment: You are only checking if the element is duplicated as the first element of the accumulator, you need to search on the whole accumulator as you did in your recursive function. [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/GJhZdJisSvOSnOsIbTFUfw/2) is a template with all the boilerplate, you only need to fill the condition; there is also an alternative version that uses a **Set** to improve performance.

Comment: The code that is now visible returns List(3, 1, 4, 2, 1) . The numbers are fine, but how do change it so it would print Seq(1,2,4,1,3) ? (not reversed and not list but seq)

Comment: The numbers are not right, there are still duplicates. Unless you do not want to remove duplicates but consecutive repeated numbers. Anyways, for the order, you may just call `reverse` at the end or use `ls :+ item` to prepend the elements instead of appending them. Finally, it will never print **Seq** because **Seq** is just an interface, it will print whatever final implementation the runtime chose, in this case, **List**; If you really want to print **Seq** you can turn the result into a string manually like this: `.mkString("Seq(", ", ", ")")`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez prepend should be `item +: ls`.

Comment: @yangzai yeah the code was right, I mixed the words. I wanted to say _"appending instead of prepending"_.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using `foldLeft` then I would use a `Vector`:

```scala
Seq(1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3).foldLeft(Vector.empty[Int]) {
  case (acc, i) if acc.lastOption.contains(i) =>  acc
  case (acc, i)                               =>  acc :+ i
}
```

Otherwise I would `foldRight` with a `List` instead:

```scala
Seq(1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3).foldRight(List.empty[Int]) {
  case (i, acc @ x :: _) if x == i  =>  acc
  case (i, acc)                     =>  i :: acc
}
```

Comment: Can also `seq.reverse.foldLeft(List.empty)...` :)

Comment: @Dima I guess `reverse` fine since it doesn't affect the time complexity for this case, but you kind of have still have to remake the list. It's still better than appending a list within the `foldLeft` though - that would definity affect time complexity.